# Not sure how to produce a plot from existed datasets package

Tags: r

[image]
Just feel confused about question 2 part b and c which asked to produce a plot based on the data provided.
the link below gives out the data requires to produce the plot
https://www.openintro.org/data/index.php?data=county

Want to see how the result for part b and c come out, thanks a lot.

Comment: do you know anything about scatter plots?  Well then google on how to create some scatter plots in R. Hint use the `plot` function

Comment: I tried for both google and youtube, both of them made me more confused...

Comment: First read the data into R, then use the plot function.

Comment: http://sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-scatter-plots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization#basic-scatter-plots

Comment: Thanks, this website helps a lot, additionally, what if I have two catrgories (population in 2010 and polulation in 2017) for y-axis to put in one plot, then what will be the code looks like.

Comment: Then you have two y-axes on one plot—imagine how that would be presented. Google it and you will find answers. You would still need something to be on your x-axis.